# How to match files with `find` in bash - also in subdirectories?

Tags: linux, bash, find

In linux bash, I have directories like this:

```
.
├── index.md
├── rss.conf
└── tech
    └── comp.md
```

Where I'm trying to have a list of relative filenames to all `*.md` files. Looking up some answers here, I've collected: `find -name *.md`

Which only outputs `./index.md`

(Weirdly, If I run the command after a `cd ../` it does find all `*.md`.)

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -name *.md
```

only finds index.md because the command actually expands to

```
find . -name index.md
```

That is, `find` only sees the one name. (That is how globs work – they expand in the shell before the command is ever executed.)

What you need to do is simply wrap the command in quotes, so the glob doesn't expand.

```
find . -name '*.md'
```

In general, if you want to understand why a command is not doing as you expect, run `set -x` in the shell. That will cause it to output the real command before invoking it.

```
$ set -x
+ set -x
$ find . -name *.md
+ find . -name index.md
./index.md
$ find . -name '*.md'
+ find . -name '*.md'
./index.md
./tech/comp.md
```

Answer (score 4):

Quotes!

```
find . -name '*.md'
```

Otherwise, if any file with a name ending in `.md` exists in the current directory, the glob is expanded by your shell (replaced with a list of matching filenames in the current directory) before `find` is started.

Note that the `.` argument (indicating the locations to start from) can be omitted only in GNU `find`; including it explicitly is the more portable practice.

Comment: Any difference in single vs double quotes in this scenario?

Comment: Not in this scenario. I tend to advise single-quotes unless there's a specific reason to use double quotes, since single quotes are the more explicit form (it's obvious to a reader that no expansions will take place, even without looking at the contents).